Joining two lists by matching elements of the two
Suppose I have two lists of the following form:
List1 = {{"c", 3.5}, {"a", 2.2}, {"d", 1.2}, {"b", 0.5}};
List2 = {{"a", 1}, {"b", 3}, {"c", 5}, {"d", 9}};

I want to create a new list that essentially matches the letters and gives me the two numerical values for the letters, it should give the following:
List3={{"a", 1, 2.2}, {"b", 3, 0.5}, {"c", 5, 3.5}, {"d", 9, 1.2}}

I’m probably missing a very straightforward solution to this, but I’m struggling to find it.

lis1 = {{"c", 3.5}, {"a", 2.2}, {"d", 1.2}, {"b", 0.5}}
lis2 = {{"a", 1}, {"b", 3}, {"c", 5}, {"d", 9}}
lis = Join[lis1, lis2]
h = Union@Map[First, lis] (*to pick the letters*)

And now
Map[ Function[{x}, Flatten@{x, Cases[lis, {x, y_} :> y]}], h]


I bet there are 9 more ways to do this in Mathematica.

If you formulate your lists as associations,
A1 = Association @@ Rule @@@ List1
(*    <|"c" -> 3.5, "a" -> 2.2, "d" -> 1.2, "b" -> 0.5|>    *)
A2 = Association @@ Rule @@@ List2
(*    <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 3, "c" -> 5, "d" -> 9|>            *)

then they can be merged directly:
Merge[{A1, A2}, Identity]
(*    <|"c" -> {3.5, 5}, "a" -> {2.2, 1}, "d" -> {1.2, 9}, "b" -> {0.5, 3}|>    *)


KeyValueMap[Prepend[#2, #1] &, Merge[{Rule @@@ List2, Rule @@@ List1}, Identity]]
(* {{"a", 1, 2.2}, {"b", 3, 0.5}, {"c", 5, 3.5}, {"d", 9, 1.2}} *)

If your actual data isn't sorted nicely, and you want a sorted result:
SortBy[
  KeyValueMap[Prepend[#2, #1] &, Merge[{Rule @@@ List2, Rule @@@ List1}, Identity]], 
  First]


l1 = {{"c", 3.5}, {"a", 2.2}, {"d", 1.2}, {"b", 0.5}};

l2 = {{"a", 1}, {"b", 3}, {"c", 5}, {"d", 9}};


Using the third argument of GroupBy:
f = Values[
Sort@GroupBy[Join[#1, #2], First, 
  DeleteDuplicates@*Join @@ 
    ReverseSortBy[#, MatchQ[#[[2]], _Integer] &] &]] &;

f[l1, l2]


{{"a", 1, 2.2}, {"b", 3, 0.5}, {"c", 5, 3.5}, {"d", 9, 1.2}}

Or using GroupBy and SortBy:
f = Values@GroupBy[Sort@Join[#1, #2], 
    First, {#1[[1]], Splice@SortBy[#2, ! IntegerQ[#] &]} & @@ Thread@# &] &;

f[l1, l2]


{{"a", 1, 2.2}, {"b", 3, 0.5}, {"c", 5, 3.5}, {"d", 9, 1.2}}

Or using Association:
sortPair = SortBy[#, ! IntegerQ[#] &] &@*Identity;
assoc = Partition[Sort[Association@*Rule @@@ Join @@ #], Length@#] &;

Merge[assoc@{l1, l2}, sortPair]

(*<|"a" -> {1, 2.2}, "b" -> {3, 0.5}, "c" -> {5, 3.5}, "d" -> {9, 1.2}|>*)

KeyValueMap[{#1, Splice@#2} &]@%

(*{{"a", 1, 2.2}, {"b", 3, 0.5}, {"c", 5, 3.5}, {"d", 9, 1.2}}*)


alist = {{"c", 3.5}, {"a", 2.2}, {"d", 1.2}, {"b", 0.5}};
blist = {{"a", 1}, {"b", 3}, {"c", 5}, {"d", 9}};

Join[alist, blist] // SortBy[First] // 
  SequenceCases[#, k : {{a_, _} ..} :> {a, Sequence @@ Last /@ k}] & //
  SortBy[Position[alist, First@#] &]

Join[alist, blist] // Map[Apply[Rule]] // Merge[Identity] // 
 KeyValueMap[{#1, Sequence @@ #2} &]

Merge[Rule @@@ Join[alist, blist], Identity] // 
 KeyValueMap[{#1, Sequence @@ #2} &]



{{"c", 3.5, 5}, {"a", 1, 2.2}, {"d", 1.2, 9}, {"b", 0.5, 3}}


Associations would be the more elegant approach but I wanted to mention a method that doesn't use them.
Prepend[Last[#], #[[1,1]]] & /@ Transpose /@ GatherBy[Join[List1, List2], First]

This code assumes that the structures of List1 and List2 are consistent with what is shown in the question.  It also will not eliminate duplicates; i.e., if the intersection of List1 and List2 is nonempty, then the common elements will appear more than once in the output.  If this behavior is not desired, use Union[] instead of Join[].

Here is a solution:
List1 = {{"c", 3.5}, {"a", 2.2}, {"d", 1.2}, {"b", 0.5}};
List2 = {{"a", 1}, {"b", 3}, {"c", 5}, {"d", 9}};
List1 = Association[#1 -> #2 & @@@ List1];
List2 = Association[#1 -> #2 & @@@ List2];
Table[{k, List1[k], List2[k] /. _Missing -> Nothing}, {k, 
  Sort@Keys[List1]}]
(*{{"a", 2.2, 1}, {"b", 0.5, 3}, {"c", 3.5, 5}, {"d", 1.2, 9}}*)```

